# Shut off page generated by \part?

Tags: latex

My MWE adds "Part One: ..." to my TOC like I want but also generates a "Part" page. How do I shut off the part page so I can insert one in the formatting I want?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\let\ordinal\relax
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\printtoctitle}[1]{\centering\HUGE\textit{Contents}}

\usepackage{fmtcount}
\renewcommand{\cftpartleader}{}
\renewcommand*{\cftpartfont}{}
\renewcommand\partnumberline[1]{\centering\huge\scshape Part #1: }
\renewcommand*{\cftpartformatpnum}[1]{}
\renewcommand{\thepart}{\Numberstring{part}}

\patchcmd\l@part{%
  {\cftpartfont {#1}}\cftpartfillnum{#2}%
}{%
  #1\cftpartfillnum{#2}%
}{\typeout{patched}%
}{}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents*
\part{The Theory}
\part{The Foundation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The Part page I want to stop from being generated:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below shows you where you can insert you own part page. I left the original code, so you can see how to access the part names etc.:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\makeatletter
\long\def\@part[#1]#2{%
  \M@gettitle{#1}%
  \def\f@rtoc{#1}%
  \@nameuse{part@f@rtoc@before@write@hook}%
  \phantomsection
  \mempreaddparttotochook
  \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >-2\relax
    \refstepcounter{part}%
    \addcontentsline{toc}{part}%
      {\protect\partnumberline{\thepart}\f@rtoc}%
    \mempartinfo{\thepart}{\f@rtoc}{#2}%
  \else
    \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\f@rtoc}%
    \mempartinfo{}{\f@rtoc}{#2}%
  \fi
  \mempostaddparttotochook
  \partmark{#1}%
  {%
% ------------------ starts the part page
   \centering
   \interlinepenalty \@M
   \parskip\z@
   \normalfont
   \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >-2\relax
     \printpartname \partnamenum \printpartnum
     \midpartskip
   \fi
   \printparttitle{#2}\par%
% ------------------ ends the part page
   }%
  \@endpart}
\makeatother

\let\ordinal\relax
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\printtoctitle}[1]{\centering\HUGE\textit{Contents}}

\usepackage{fmtcount}
\renewcommand{\cftpartleader}{}
\renewcommand*{\cftpartfont}{}
\renewcommand\partnumberline[1]{\centering\huge\scshape Part #1: }
\renewcommand*{\cftpartformatpnum}[1]{}
\renewcommand{\thepart}{\Numberstring{part}}

\patchcmd\l@part{%
  {\cftpartfont {#1}}\cftpartfillnum{#2}%
}{%
  #1\cftpartfillnum{#2}%
}{\typeout{patched}%
}{}



\begin{document}
\tableofcontents*
\part{The Theory}
\part{The Foundation}
text
\end{document}
```